Preview in Android Studio doesn't use the font
I have a very simple Jetpack-Compose composable function:
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun QuoteScreen() {
    QuoteAppTheme {
        Text(
            "Hello World",
            fontFamily = cursiveFontFamily
        )

    }
}

The Text has a custom font from Google Fonts, which has been defined in Type.kt with:
val provider = GoogleFont.Provider(
    providerAuthority = "com.google.android.gms.fonts",
    providerPackage = "com.google.android.gms",
    certificates = R.array.com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs
)

val cursiveFontFamily = FontFamily(
    Font(
        googleFont = GoogleFont("Shadows Into Light Two"),
        fontProvider = provider
    )
)

When I run the app or the preview in the emulator, the font is applied correctly
But in the preview of Android Studio, the font is not applied. Can we fix that somehow?
